# ColdFusion having multiple cfqueries in cffunction

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to write a function for a survey where it pulls questions from a database. The catch is that there are both active and unactive questions. I need older questions to show up when someone views the results from an old survey.

Here is the code I am trying within a CFC:

```
<cffunction name="getAllQuestions" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="survey" default=0>
    <cfif len(#survey#) gt 0>
    <cfquery name="getsdate" datasource="blah.database">
    select * from past_survey
    where survey_id = #survey#
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn getsdate>
    </cfif>
    <cfquery name="getquestions" datasource="blah.database">
        select * from pool_questions
        <cfif len(#survey#) eq 0> 
        where active_flag='Y'
        <cfelse>
        where <cfqueryparam value="#dateformat 
                       (getsdate.survey_date, "yyyy/mm/dd")#"> BETWEEN start_date AND  
                       end_date
        </cfif>   
        order by qtn_nb
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn getquestions>
</cffunction>
```

`#survey#` is the survey id which is generated by the form. What I am trying to do is that if `survey` has a value to run query getsdate. Then the second query would run no matter if `survey` has a value or not. If there is not value it should pull all active questions. If there is a value then it should check if the survey date is between the start date and end date for past questions.

Any advice on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"#survey# is the survey id which is generated by the form."_ - then your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks by the users. Use [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) to fix this.  Also, don't write `len(#survey#) gt 0` - just `len(survey)` is all you need.

Comment: _Then the second query would run no matter if survey has a value or not_ - That is not true based on your code. If `survey` is greater than `0` then after the getsdate query runs the function will return without running the second query. Because of the `<cfreturn getsdate>` code.

Comment: I would also try to avoid using `select *` in your queries.  Instead, specify all of the columns that you need (and only those columns that you need).

Comment: Thanks I will make these changes.

Comment: That is just the header of the error message. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14364292/edit) to include the complete error message.

Comment: I actually fixed the error for the cfqueryparam should I add it to everylocation survey is located. Sorry I am still new to Coldfusion. Thanks

Comment: If in doubt, use cfqueryparam, but here's a blog post that goes into detail: http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/what-one-can-and-cannot-do-with.html

Answer (score 4):

```
    <cffunction name="getAllQuestions" access="public" returntype="struct">
        <cfargument name="survey" required="true" default="0" type="numeric">

        <cfset var qryReturn                    = ""> <!---Always var scope your variables to prevent them from leaking to other functions --->
        <cfset var structReturn                 = structNew()>
        <cfset structReturn.pastSurvey          = "">
        <cfset structReturn.surveyQuestions     = "">

        <cfif survey GT 0>
            <cfquery name="qryReturn" datasource="blah.database">
                SELECT * 
                FROM   past_survey
                <!--- Always cfqueryparam to prevent SQL injection attacks & also always reference the scope to prevent confusion --->
                WHERE  survey_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.survey#">
            </cfquery>
            <cfset structReturn.pastSurvey = qryReturn>
       <cfelse>
            <cfquery name="qryReturn" datasource="blah.database">
                 SELECT *
                 FROM pool_questions
                 <cfif arguments.survey EQ 0>
                     WHERE active_flag = 'Y'
                 <cfelse>
                     WHERE <cfqueryparam value="#dateformat 
                       (getsdate.survey_date, "yyyy/mm/dd")#"> BETWEEN start_date AND  
                       end_date
                 </cfif>
                 ORDER BY qtn_nb
             </cfquery>
             <cfset structReturn.surveyQuestions = qryReturn>
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn structReturn>
    </cffunction>
```

You probably should be doing this in two separate functions, but I will attempt to answer your question.

My code will return a struct of  queries (you can change to an array if you prefer) that returns a past survey and the survey questions

Note: In your example code, you have a few bad practices.

1. You are checking the length of the survey value rather than checking the value itself.
2. If you want to ensure that survey always has a value regardless of if it is passed or not, set `requried=true` and give it a default value.
3. Use `cfqueryparam` to prevent sql injection attacks
4. Any variables created in the function need to be `var` scoped to prevent them from leaking to other cffunctions in the same cfcomponent.  I always do this at the top. Yes, even the name you give a cfquery needs to be var scoped.
5. Since you are doing a return after your first query, if the survey value is greater than 0 it will never get to the second query where it has the date check.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and tips I am new to coldfusion so all your advice is greatly appreicated.

Comment: _My code will return a struct of queries_ - you need to change the `returnType` in the function declaration.

Comment: Fyi, returnType typo fixed.

Comment: In #2 I believe the opposite is true; you want to set `required=false` and give it a default value. However, I just checked the documentation and for the `required` attribute it states _Specifies whether the parameter is required to execute the component method. The parameter is not required if you specify a default attribute._  So I guess it will work either way.  (Learn something new every day...)

Comment: @Miguel-F - I was about to leave a comment I tweaked that line for clarity :P Since applying a `default` is akin to an implicit `required=false`. (Edit was reversed it to preserve thread context) Though it works either way. I usually omit `required` when `default` is used. But that is just  personal preference thing. I completely agree with the rest of Tim's points, so +1 there.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I am convinced you should be doing this several smaller individual functions in same cfc.  A book I can't recommend enough is Object-Oriented Programming in ColdFusion by Matt Gifford. Also learncfinaweek.com is a great source of free learning.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following problems you need to address.

First, your survey argument has a default value of 0 and you are doing conditional logic on the length of it.  The length of "0" is 1, so that condition will always return true.

Next, you state that you want the 2nd query to run whether the first one runs or not, but you refer to a value from the 1st query in the 2nd one.  That means if the 1st query does not run, the 2nd one will crash due to an undefined variable.

Next, dateformat returns a string.  Applying it the way you do in the 2nd query is at best unnecessary, and at worse, and indication that you are storing the start and end dates in pool_questions as strings.  If you are attempting to strip out the time portion of the datefield in the first query, ColdFusion has a cast() function for that.

Also, scope your variables.  ie - instead of `<cfif len(survey)`, do this `<cfif len(arguments.survey)`.

Also, var your local variables.  In this case, it's the names of your two queries.

That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you I am still learning coldfusion so all your advice is greatly appreicated.

Comment: Depending on the database driver, it _might_ be necessary to use dateformat to get dates correctly handled - however, if that's the case it should also be accompanied by an appropriate cfsqltype attribute to make sure it is treated as a date, not a varchar.

Comment: *ColdFusion has a cast() function for that* Are you talking about the QoQ `cast(column as date)` function? It does not truncate time. However, using `cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"` does.